# How do I change the elevation in react navigation bottom tab bar?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[Elevation is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVt98.png)

I want to change elevation in react navigation bottom tab bar and I want to change bottom tab bar height.

Comment: Can you add minimal code to reproduce? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, supposing that you are using `createBottomTabNavigator` to create your bottom tab navigator, you can customize look and feel by using `tabBarOptions` option like this:

```
const MyTabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ... // here your screens
},
{
  animationEnabled: true,  // maybe you want an animation?
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom', // tab bar is on bottom of the screen
  tabBarOptions: {   // here your style customization
    showLabel: true,  // you want ot show label under the icon?
    style:{
      elevation: 3,   // here set your elevation
      height: 50      // here set your height
    },
  },
});
```